# Store Model targets + AR Content in Cloud-Database and just download a few to the device (Unity+Vuforia)

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am quite new to AR-Programming and do not have a lot of experience with Unity+Vuforia.

In my current project I have about 200 different model targets with different AR content.
If the User opens the App, he/she needs to enter a serial number. According to the number the program should get the related model targets from a database.
*e.g. entered Number: 123 --> Model target 2, Model target 57 and Model target 198 needed*

So the user just needs the the Model targets 2, 57 and 198 + AR content to be loaded on his/her App. He never needs the rest of the model targets, so it would just be a huge amount of unused data on the device if everything is stored locally.

Question: Is it possible to store all model targets +AR Content in a database (e.g. cloud database?) and just download the necessary ones to the device?
And if it is- how :) ?